# "Invalid command" error with git_remote_connect

Tags: c++, libgit2

I'm actually try to use libgit2 with C++ to commit and push in a git repository.
No problem with HTTPS but with SSH I have the error :

*git_remote_connect : Invalid command: 'XXX 'YYY/test.git''
You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.
Make sure your core.gitProxy config option and the
GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable are NOT set*

After long research I finally found where my problem normally comes from.
In git_remote_connect the third argument is a git_remote_callbacks.
I need to define a payload in this callbacks.
The payload need to be a git_strarray containing two string but **I have absolutly no idea of what string I'm supposed to write**. A shell command? A c++ function? An username?

If I don't add the payload in the callbacks, I have the error  :
*"invalid ssh paths, must be two strings"*

I create a payload :

```
char * str1 = "";
char * str2 = "XXX"; //The string that appear in the error message
char * astr[2]; 
astr[0] = str1;
astr[1] = str2;
git_strarray payload = {astr, 2};
push_options.callbacks.payload = &payload;
```

My question is: Did you know what I'm supposed to write in the two string of the payload?

---

## Solved

I solved my problem: I added transport to my callbacks, that's why that didn't work. Thank you Carlosmn for your patience!
There is a slack for libgit2, you can join it if you have problem: http://slack.libgit2.org/

Comment: I tried to look at the doc https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/remote/git_remote_connect but that signature does not match what you describe. Which version of libgit2 are you using? It looks like it might be options for proxy or something like that.

Comment: Sorry i make a little mistake, the third parameter is a callback that I have from a git_push_options. : git_remote_connect(remote, GIT_DIRECTION_PUSH, &(push_options.callbacks), &(push_options.custom_headers))

Comment: Nobody has any idea of what I'm supposed to write in the two string?

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.